# Prestashop 1.7 need tax included in total only, not in product price

Tags: prestashop, cart, prestashop-1.7, calculation, tax

I know enough about programming to tinker a little, but MVC models are still baffling to me. I need a way to have the checkout total include the cost of taxes, but I do not want the product price to include the price of taxes. The tax amount already shows as a line item, but when I use the "tax incl" method it changes the product price and gives me a total that does include tax. On the other hand if I use the "tax excl" method, the product price is correct but the total does not include the tax. Example pictures attached PS version 1.7.3.2
[Tax excl image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYlsE.png
[Tax incl image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWIta.png

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you need help on a programming question, please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. We prefer concrete, textual information over screen shots. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/2311167. You also might want to consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

I did following and it works for me in prestashop 1.7.5.0: 
To do so, we must edit the file:

themes/classic/templates/checkout/_partials/cart-summary-totals.tpl

and add this code where you want to show the total of the cart:

{$currency.iso_code}{$currency.sign}{$cart.totals.total.amount+$cart.subtotals.tax.amount}